# I want a function to return an array in processing.js, the code works until I put the array into a conditional

Tags: arrays, return, processing.js

Here is the code, it works fine without the conditional, but once I put it there the code gives me "the method must return a result of type String[]"

I have tried everything by now and hope you guys can see whats wrong here. 
This topic is talked a lot about on the net, but none of the solutions give 
me any closure on the matter. Its probably something very simple that I 
keep looking over.

Also, the first bit of code does not want to get int the code box, sorry about that.

```
String []loadString (String A){

if(A.equals("YEP")){ 

    //Array
    String []IS = {
      "#FFFCFCFC", "S10", "nameString", "print",
      "newlineS8", "S4", "smallspace", "print", "G8",  "nameGraph",
      "newlineS7", "G4", "nationalityGraph", "S3", "space", "print", "elementGraph", "space",        "print" ,"sexGraph",
      "newlineS1", 
      "newlineS1","G2","point","S2","listA","print",
      "newlineS1","G2","point","S2","listB","print", 
      "newlineS1","G2","point","S2","listC","print",
      "newlineS1","G2","point","S2","listD","print", 
      "newlineS4" };

      return  IS;

    }
}

void draw() {

 String IS[] = loadString ("YEP"); // when I send the string "yep" the array should be loaded 
 println(IS);
 noLoop();  
}
```

Comment: Is loadString() an actual separate function, or is your code written exactly like you presented it here?

Comment: Its exactly written like that, as far as I know its not "used" by processing.js, yep I just tested it, changing loadString into something else does not make the error go away.

Comment: Right, sorry, didn't see the first line of code that didn't get into the formatting. Added an edit for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Sorry for the delay, hope this is still helpful.)

Hmm, I think the reason you're getting an error is because your function `loadString()` needs to return a String[] whenever it is called, since that is its return type.

Without the if statement it will always return `String[] IS`. However, when you add that if statement, it is possible that no such result will be returned, since the entire declaration and returning of `String[] IS` is wrapped inside the if statement. (For example, if I changed the argument, and called `loadString("NOPE")` instead of `loadString("YEP")`, what would `loadString()` return? Nothing, because the condition failed, so nothing inside the if statement ran.)

One way to avoid this is to have a default return value, so a result of the correct type will always be returned, and only change its value to something meaningful if the condition is met. Here's a modification of `loadString()` that seems to work in Processing.js (I'm a bit new to Processing too, so I hope there's nothing wrong with this approach):

```
String []loadString (String A){

  String[] IS = {""};

  if(A.equals("YEP")){ 

    //Array
    IS = new String[] {
      "#FFFCFCFC", "S10", "nameString", "print",
      "newlineS8", "S4", "smallspace", "print", "G8",  "nameGraph",
      "newlineS7", "G4", "nationalityGraph", "S3", "space", "print", "elementGraph", "space",        "print" ,"sexGraph",
      "newlineS1", 
      "newlineS1","G2","point","S2","listA","print",
      "newlineS1","G2","point","S2","listB","print", 
      "newlineS1","G2","point","S2","listC","print",
      "newlineS1","G2","point","S2","listD","print", 
      "newlineS4" };

    }

    return  IS;
}
```

Note how I initially set `String[] IS` to an array with a single empty string, and only change its value in the if statement. This way, even if the condition fails, `String[] IS` will still get returned, so the function will return a result of the proper type.

Hope this helps! Let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: Yes, its still helpful!! Thanx :) and your explanation is very clear.

Comment: Great! If this answer solved the problem, don't forget to mark it as the accepted answer. (Click the checkmark outline on the left of the answer.)